# ArgumentOutOfRangeException from SelectionChanged event WinRT

Tags: c#, json, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Alright. I'm developing a Windows 8 (WinRT) app with C# and XAML, and I have a listbox which contains quite a few elements fetched from JSON. When you click one of the items, you'll be transferred to a new page showing the whole news item. **This works.**

However, whenever I click an item and I'm transferred, and I click the backbutton on the phone, the app crashes. I'm getting the following error, and I have no idea why it doesn't work! Any ideas?

[image: ArgumentOutOfRangeException]

```
        private void NewsList_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        index = NewsList.SelectedIndex;

        NewsItems newsContentGetSet = new NewsItems();

        newsContentGetSet.news_id = newslistJson.ElementAt(index).news_id;
        newsContentGetSet.news_title = newslistJson.ElementAt(index).news_title;
        newsContentGetSet.news_abstract = newslistJson.ElementAt(index).news_abstract;
        newsContentGetSet.news_content = newslistJson.ElementAt(index).news_content;
        newsContentGetSet.news_author = newslistJson.ElementAt(index).news_author;
        newsContentGetSet.news_date_formatted = newslistJson.ElementAt(index).news_date_formatted;
        newsContentGetSet.user_firstname = newslistJson.ElementAt(index).user_firstname;
        newsContentGetSet.user_lastname = newslistJson.ElementAt(index).user_lastname;

        App.newsContentGetSet = newsContentGetSet;
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/NewsPage.xaml?language=" + chosenLanguage, UriKind.Relative));        
    }
```

**Exception:**

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled   Message= Parameter
>   name: index   StackTrace:
>          at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(ExceptionArgument
>   argument, ExceptionResource resource)
>          at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException()
>          at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item(Int32 index)
>          at System.Linq.Enumerable.ElementAt[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Int32 index)
>          at MunchApp3._0.MainPage.NewsList_SelectionChanged_1(Object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs
>   e)
>          at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.InvokeSelectionChanged(List`1
>   unselectedItems, List`1 selectedItems)
>          at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.SelectionChanger.End()
>          at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Selector.OnItemsChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs
>   e)
>          at System.Windows.Controls.ListBox.OnItemsChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs
>   e)
>          at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.OnItemCollectionChanged(Object
>   sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.NotifyCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs
>   e)
>          at System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection.UpdateItemsSourceList(IEnumerable
>   newItemsSource)
>          at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.ItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject
>   d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.DependencyObject.RaisePropertyChangeNotifications(DependencyProperty
>   dp, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
>          at System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(DependencyProperty
>   property, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry& newEntry,
>   ValueOperation operation)
>          at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(DependencyProperty
>   dp, Object value, Boolean allowReadOnlySet)
>          at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueInternal(DependencyProperty
>   dp, Object value)
>          at System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
>          at System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.set_ItemsSource(IEnumerable
>   value)
>          at MunchApp3._0.MainPage.webClientNews_DownloadStringCompleted(Object
>   sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
>          at System.Net.WebClient.OnDownloadStringCompleted(DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs
>   e)
>          at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadStringOperationCompleted(Object arg)
>          at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo
>   rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object
>   parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly
>   caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>          at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters,
>   CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>          at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
>          at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args)
>          at System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
>          at System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(DispatcherPriority
>   priority)
>          at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(Object context)
>          at System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(Object[] args)
>          at System.Windows.Hosting.DelegateWrapper.InternalInvoke(Object[] args)
>          at System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(IntPtr pHandle, Int32 nParamCount, ScriptParam[] pParams, ScriptParam&
>   pResult)

Comment: Could you possibly copy that exception and post it as text in your question? While you're at it, post your code, too. Having to copy/paste the image is too much work. What is the value of `NewsList.SelectedIndex` when you enter the method?

Comment: @JimMischel Tried breakpoint'ing from the method start, where it has index 0.

Comment: And you're sure that there are items in the `newslist.Json` collection? Have you checked the `Count` property (or return value of the `Count()` method)?

Comment: Yeah, it has two (2) items. And that's the weird thing, since newslistJson populates the Listbox upon the start of the app, which works. It only crashes after actually entering one of the listbox items (which works), and then returning to the MainPage.xaml page, where it crashes.

Comment: So when the exception is thrown, `SelectedIndex` is 0, and `newslist.Json` contains 2 items? That's ... unusual. How about putting a test in the code that says, `if (NewsList.SelectedIndex < 0 || NewsList.SelectedIndex >= newslist.Json.Count) { throw new Exception(); }` ... put a breakpoint on the `throw` and see what happens when you run your program.

Comment: Hm, we actually got it working just by adding a bool which checks whether the app has already downloaded the JSON file or not, so now it works - almost. If you've accessed a listbox item (forwards you to newspage.xaml), gone back to the listbox (mainpage.xaml) and try the same listbox item again, it doesn't fire the event handler. We've tried resetting the SelectedIndex to -1 too, but it won't work correctly.

Comment: Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150575/select-an-item-two-or-more-times (answer 1)

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
{
   NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/NewsPage.xaml?language=" + chosenLanguage, UriKind.Relative));
});
```